# How to work with GestureDetector in a Stateful Widget without Performance Issues?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a slider that works with GestureDetector in a stateful widget. The problem is that every time if I move the slider the whole stateful widget is regenerated. Since the SomePainter recalculates and reloads content every time, this doesn't look nice because the content always disappears briefly and then comes back.

Is there any way to change only the SetState for a specific CustomPainter in this view or how could you nest multiple Stateful widgets so that the main view is not always reloaded?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../slider/pointer.dart';

class Slider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SliderState createState() => _SliderState();
}

class _SliderState extends State<Slider> {
  Offset globalPosition;
  final GlobalKey paintKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomPaint(
              painter: SomePainter(),
              child: Container(),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
              onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
              child: CustomPaint(
                key: paintKey,
                painter: SliderPointer(globalPosition, paintKey),
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      globalPosition = details.globalPosition;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: From an architecture perspective, your painter should only paint. Not load things. Do you have the option of reloading content for your painter outside of the painter and using it as a parameter, so you can load the content once and pass it to your painter (for example let's say the list of textures... should not be loaded on every paint cycle).

Comment: @nvoigt, yes, I load some content and pass it to the painter. but if I move my slider the whole widget is loading and pass it again and again with every move.

Comment: You may also provide a better override to the [shouldRepaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter/shouldRepaint.html) method, so you don't repaint at all.

Comment: I think that is my problem. I did not implement a correct shouldRepaint method. Thanks.